# How to find groups with most recent messages?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `messages` and `groups`

### messages

`id, content, group_id, created_at`

### groups

`id, created_at`

I want to find the `n` number of groups sorted by the most recent messages in them. How can I do that with PostgreSQL 14?

I'm running the following query but it's not giving the expected result.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT id, group_id, created_at, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ) AS rn
   FROM messages order by created_at desc
) sub;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: This is the current output - https://imgur.com/a/kvrhpoA

Comment: But I'm expecting only 1 message with highest row number per group_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to let `ORDER BY created_at desc` in window function which might help you get highest row number per group_id

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id order by created_at desc) AS rn
   FROM messages 
) sub
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Your answer appended by `order by created_at desc` worked!